# Add one row to database instead of multiple rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, repeater

So currently my code dynamically adds data from a Visual Studio Repeater into a database. My code below works well except for one main issue. During my foreach loop, it creates a new row for each Repeater textbox. Instead, I want it to create 1 row altogether.

For example, my Repeater could have FirstName and LastName as columns. In my Repeater, it could collect this data, such as John for the FirstName and Smith for the LastName. It should enter John Smith into one row of the table, but it actually adds John as row 1 and Smith as row 2.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code that dynamically adds the data to the database:

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in RepeaterForm.Items)
            {

                Label lblDisplayName = rpItem.FindControl("lblDisplayName") as Label;
                Label lblColumnName = rpItem.FindControl("lblColumnName") as Label;
                TextBox txtColumnValue = rpItem.FindControl("txtColumnValue") as TextBox;

                if (txtColumnValue != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = "spInsFormRegistrant";
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();

                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eventId;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = formId;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lblColumnName.Text;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtColumnValue.Text;

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    PnlNone.Visible = false;
    PnlExist.Visible = false;
    PnlSuccess.Visible = true;
    PnlFail.Visible = false;
}
```

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsFormRegistrant]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @EventId int,
     @FormId int,
     @ColumnName varchar(100),
     @ColumnValue varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 -- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @Query nvarchar(4000)
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

set @Query = 'INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ 
             (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)'
set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int'
exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID

END
```

**EDIT**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsFormRegistrant]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @EventId int,
     @FormId int,
     @ColumnName varchar(100),
     @ColumnValue varchar(100)
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @searchID int

 -- Insert statements for procedure here

IF  @searchID IS null
 BEGIN

declare @Query nvarchar(4000)
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)

    set @Query = 'INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ 
             (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)
                set @searchID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'

    set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int, @searchID INT OUTPUT'
    exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID,
                   @searchID = @searchID OUTPUT;
END
IF  @searchID IS NOT null
BEGIN
declare @Query2 nvarchar(4000)
declare @ParmDefinition2 nvarchar(500)

    set @Query2 = 'UPDATE Registrant SET DateCreated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, EventId = @EventId, FormId = @FormId, ' +quotename(@ColumnName)+ ' =  @ColumnValue WHERE RegistrantId = @searchID'
    set @ParmDefinition2 = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int, @searchID int'
    exec sp_executesql @Query2, @ParmDefinition2, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID,
                   @searchID = @searchID
END
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you make insert for each field separated. The way you do it you must make the first as insert, the other as update.

Note here:

```
'INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ 
        (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)
```

The `@ColumnName` is variable, and you insert only one field at every time!

Probably you get that code from some example, and not fit in your program. You need to re-write the code to do what you try to do, by inserting all fields at ones, or run an UPDATE command if the row all ready exist.

Comment: If I do the insert and then update route, is there a way to grab that row id after it did that initial insert? Otherwise I would not be sure how to update the correct row

Comment: Please see my edited code. I created an insert and then update. Still places in multiple columns... I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are executing your stored procedure for each item in the repeater.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using foreach? I believe I need to loop through each item in the repeater in order to dynamically get the fields.

Comment: That is correct, but you should execute your stored procedure once you've read all values required for a row. Currently you execute it for each parameter you read from your repeater and expect it to create a row.